# Set data type (xml) for a field in data table, using Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, xml, visual-studio, datatable

Hi I have datatype for a field recently converted to xml from varchar(MAX) in SqlServer DB.
I want to set this type for the corresponing field in the data table, but it has no option for xml. Any suggestion ?

Thanks

using VS 08 and SQL SERVER 08

[alt text http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/3888/53987921.jpg](http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/3888/53987921.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL type `xml` will convert happily enough to System.String. I'd use that.